# What is the reason of negative value (error) in Bulk Transfer Android?

Tags: android, usb

I'm working on [bulkTransfer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/usb/UsbDeviceConnection.html) . It returns length of data transferred (or zero) for success, or negative value for failure.

I want to know the reason of negative value. For example I got -1 and what are the causes it becomes -1? Does I send wrong data or not enough memory or controller busy or etc...

Windows has [GetLastError](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681383(v=vs.85).aspx) function. It returns error code. We can know the real reason of why it becoming error. For example,  **0x3E9** means **ERROR_STACK_OVERFLOW**.

How can I know the reason of negative value in bulkTransfer function?

Comment: Do you still have this problem or manage to resolve ?

Comment: @DigTheCode I still didn't figure out the reason of it. Android Studio may not provides it reason